# Memory leak with a recursive sub using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I'm creating a script that will allow a user to search within a specified directory with a search term. The script will create a CSV file and then write the base file name, the file size, the last modified date, and the absolute path of files that contain the search term within the file name. However, I'm running into an issue searching subfolders within the folder. The issue is that I'm running out of memory within the subroutine.

Here is the script I've written thus far.

```
Dim fileCount, searchPath, searchTerm, CheckFile, wholePath
Dim objFSO, objFolder, objFile, objWriteFile
Dim savePath

objCheckFile = "C:\Users\USERFILE\Desktop\Audit.csv"

Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Asks for directory to search in
searchPath = InputBox("Please enter the path of the folder you would like to search", "Where am I searching?")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(searchPath)

'Asks for the search term to use
searchTerm = InputBox("Please enter the term you would like to search for", "What am I searching?")

If objFSO.FileExists(objCheckFile) Then
    WScript.Echo "Please delete the file named Audit.csv before trying again"
Else
    Set objWriteFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Audit.csv", ForWriting, True)
End If

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

'Searches for files within the folder and writes to a CSV file
For Each objFile In colFiles
    If InStr(LCase(objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)), LCase(searchTerm)) > 0 Then        
        objWriteFile.Write objFSO.getFileName(objFile) & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFile.size & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFile.DateLastModified & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFSO.getAbsolutePathName(objFolder) & objFSO.getFileName(objFile) 
        objWriteFile.Writeline
    End If
Next

ShowSubFolder objFolder

Sub ShowSubFolder(Folder)
    If InStr(LCase(objFSO.GetFileName(objFile)), LCase(searchTerm)) > 0 Then
        objWriteFile.Write objFSO.getFileName(objFile) & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFile.size & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFile.DateLastModified & ", "
        objWriteFile.Write objFSO.getAbsolutePathName(objFolder) & objFSO.getFileName(objFile) 
        objWriteFile.Writeline
    End If
    For Each objSubFolder In colFolders
        ShowSubFolder objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the `Folder` parameter in your `ShowSubFolder` subroutine? It's not used anywhere in your function. The `objFolder` will always stay the same because it is the global one you set in the main code.

Answer (score 0):

Your recursion never terminates because of this:

```
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
Set colFolders = objFolder.SubFolders

'...

ShowSubFolder objFolder

Sub ShowSubFolder(Folder)
    '...
    For Each objSubFolder In colFolders
        ShowSubFolder objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

This is similar to a [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). For each subfolder of `objFolder` you recurse again into each subfolder of `objFolder`. And again. And again. And ...

Change your code to this and it should do what you want:

```
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files

'...

ShowSubFolder objFolder

Sub ShowSubFolder(Folder)
    '...
    For Each objSubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        ShowSubFolder objSubFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

You may also want to adjust the conditional inside the recursive procedure, because it uses `objFile` and `objFolder` that are defined outside the procedure.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I don't experience a memory leak anymore. However, the script doesn't seem to be writing the files located within the subfolders. I created 2 subfolders with 1 file each. These file names should be written in the CSV file but they aren't. Could that be an issue with file permissions or did I just not write the subroutine correctly?

Comment: @hidonor The code in your question does not process files in subfolders (I already hinted at that at the end of my answer). Please post a new question with your modified code as well as a sample of desired and actual output.